# Prove $x-y=0 \iff x=y$ using only field axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, axioms

We have $x - y = 0$ and we need to prove $x = y$ using only field axioms. How to prove this?

---

If I do $x-y=0 \implies x+y-y=y \implies x=y$ is this wrong?

Comment: Your title is different from your question. Are you interested in the "if-then" case or the "if and only if" case

Comment: The expression $x-y$ is an abbreviation for $x+(-y)$. Add $y$ to both sides.

Comment: @Nicolas: Adding a number to both sides is an axiom?

Comment: One direction: Suppose that $x+(-y)=0$. Then $(x+(-y))+y=0+y=y$. But $(x+(-y))+y=x+((-y)+y)=x+0=x$. The end.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You can awnser the question if you want to select yours.

Comment: Take a look at my edit so you can see how to format the mathematical parts nicely.

Comment: You are welcome. The other direction uses the same technique, except backwards and easier. From $x=y$ you get what you need by adding $-y$ to both sides.  You can even do it as an "if and only if" argument, though I advise usually going one direction at a time. You now know how to handle the problem, and there already is a solution posted, so there is no need of more.

Answer (score 4):

$\Rightarrow$

$y=y+0=y+(x-y)=x$

$\Leftarrow$

$0=y+(-y)=x+(-y)=x-y$